How do I get the data from database and generate a random result in Next.js 14?
I want to retrieve a data from my data.ts then create a function to generate a random result from my database
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import { Businesses } from './definitions';


export async function getBusinesses() {
    try {
        console.log("Fetching Businesess...");

        const data = await sql<Businesses>`SELECT * FROM businesses`;

        return data.rows;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Database Error:', error);
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch businesses data.');
    }
}

definition.ts:
export type Businesses = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    address: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    postal_code?: string;
    country: string;
    phone?: string;
    email?: string;
    website?: string;
    created_at: string;
    updated_at: string;
}

dashboard/page.tsx:
import { getBusinesses } from "../lib/data";

export default async function Dashboard() {
    const businesses = await getBusinesses();
    
    return (
        <div>            
            <h1>Dashboard Page</h1>
            <br></br>

            <h3>List of Businesses</h3>
            <ul>
                {businesses.map((business) => (
                    <li key={business.id}>{business.name}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            
            {/* button to generate random result here */}
        </div>
    );
}

I tried to use useState and useEffect but I received error fetching the data from the database saying it can't connect to my database while I didn't make any changes on my database credentials.. Please help

you can use get random result from your database with this code
export async function getRandomBusiness() {
const allBusinesses = await getBusinesses();
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allBusinesses.length);
return allBusinesses[randomIndex];

}
and if you want an array of random results use this code
export async function getRandomBusinesses(count: number) {
const allBusinesses = await getBusinesses();

// Ensure count is within valid range
count = Math.min(count, allBusinesses.length);

// Create a shuffled copy of the businesses array
const shuffledBusinesses = allBusinesses.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());

// Return the first 'count' elements of the shuffled array
return shuffledBusinesses.slice(0, count);

}

It works thanks a lot!
